# Can BIRT tool be an alternative for BI Publisher to generate reports?

Tags: report, reporting, birt, bi-publisher

I am using Oracle BI Publisher to generate reports with my java webservice call. My input source is XML files and design template is RTF. when i have huge volume of data in XML file, its throwing an out of memory at some point of time.

So, planning to have some alternative for BI publisher.

Is BIRT can fulfill my requirement?

If not, any other alternatives reporting tools to suit my requirement?

Comment: I think this question would better fit on 'Programmers'. Nonetheless 2 remarks: 1. quitting a technology because of an error is not a good strategy; make a quest for the cause and the solution, spam forums (in this case Oracle ones) and don't rest until you find it. 2. Without knowing the exact use case, I guess you could easily start working with BIRT or Jasper or any other reporting tool out there (and still encounter errors in certain cases)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems a bit obvious and is that your XML have more info than your system can process (XML processing can be very memory intense), probably using a reporting engine that makes queries directly to your database will help you to alleviate this problem, but i recommend you to do exhaustive testing before switching.

Answer (score 0):

In any question like this there are a lot of variables.  The easiest way to answer the question about BIRT is download the software at http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/ and give it a try.